# IN condition in LINQ to replace multiple OR conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have an entity framework query as shown below. Here I am trying to find entities for which there is no `fax` information for `primary` and `secondary` users. I am using two `person_role_cd` conditions using “OR”.

What is the best LINQ way to make the same logic with something like SQL “IN” condition? For example,  `p.person_role_cd IN (“Primary”, “Secondary” )`

```
query = query
.Where(l => l.loan_documents
 .FirstOrDefault(d => d.document_type_cd == “Application”)
 .loan_persons.Any(p => 
(
                                p.fax_no != null       
                                &&
                                 (
                                           p.person_role_cd == “Primary”
                                           ||
                                            p.person_role_cd == “Secondary”
                                  )
                                  )
                                  ) == false
                               );
```

Comment: @DStanley, nice find. The answer *could* differ with Linq to Entities though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET `Contains` is fairly universally translated to `IN` in my experience, so long as the list is relatively small.  Have you found instances where it doesn't work?

Comment: @DStanley Hard to say on that exact method; I just know that once I start closing over local variables bad things tend to happen.

Comment: first or default might throw a null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an array with all strings you want to check against.

```
var targetList = new[] {"Primary", "Secondary"};
```

Then Replace your `OR` condition with

```
targetList.Contains(p.person_role_cd);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Caveat: Doing stuff like this causes problems with Linq to Entities**

That said, the first thing that comes to mind is use a `List` with `Contains` (which is basically what the provided SQL does)

```
List<string> roles = new List<string>() { "Primary", "Secondary" };
query = query
.Where(l => l.loan_documents
.FirstOrDefault(d => d.document_type_cd == “Application”)
.loan_persons.Any(p => p.fax_no != null && roles.Contains(p.person_role_cd));
```

Couldn't quite tell where your negation belongs, left as exercise to the reader. The reason it *may* not work with Linq to Entities is that translating `List.Contains` (especially off of a local variable) to SQL is the kind of task it likes to give up on. If your types are literally two items, I would just keep the condition as is (apart from considering an `enum` for my types instead of strings)